# Flow to copy USER to another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Can I copy a user from one column to another? Not the separated value, but the actual user. Right now, I can't copy USERs, only their strings.

I've built a conditional flow that currently copies the USER:EMAIL from either Column A (USER) or Column B (USER) to Column C (TEXT). But instead of just the EMAIL value, I want to copy the user, whole. That would allow me to AUTOMATE from the SP LIST instead of using Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Must use the USER:EMAIL in the USER CLAIMS field in the Update Item section. Don't really understand why, other than the lookup is achieved via the email. Wish this were more obvious.